# Complex Analysis Integration of x sinmx/ x4 + a4

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

How to find this integral :-
$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(mx)}{x^4 + a^4} \, dx$

I know it is to be solved using Cauchy Residue Theorem but I am not able to get the answer. 
Thanks.

Comment: what is $sinmx$ ? And please, make an effort for writing your formula !

Comment: Please clarify your question by stating the region of integration and what the restrictions on $m$ and $a$ are.  [And please do try to format it.](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: There is no restriction on a ( as not given) and m also. But, integration is from 0 to infinity. Thanks.

Comment: @user366772: what mean $sinmx$ ? And edit your question !

Comment: Ok. Give me some time , I am trying to learn how to write a maths equation here. Sorry.

Comment: Integrate $\frac{\exp(i m x)}{x^4 + a^4}$ from 0 to R, and then over a quarter circle with radius R with center the origin to i R and then back to the origin over the imaginary axis.

Comment: @user366772 for reference http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @CountIblis you are right, but the answer that comes out is very weird. Can you please tell me the answer of this. Thanks. ( Will be editing the question soon )

Comment: Sorry for earlier , in this please add dx to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a,m>0$ we have
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(mx)}{x^4+a^4}\,dx\stackrel{\text{parity}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(mx)}{x^4+a^4}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\text{Im}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x e^{imx}}{x^4+a^4}\,dx $$
Now the function $f(x)=\frac{x e^{imx}}{x^4+a^4}$ fulfills the [ML lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) and its poles in the upper half-plane are located at $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}(\pm 1+i)$. By computing the residues there it follows that
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(mx)}{x^4+a^4}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2a^2} e^{-\frac{am}{\sqrt{2}}}\sin\left(\frac{am}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}. $$

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Grateful for it.